# How to register when modal is closed (angular2-materialize)

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, materialize

I'm trying to **doSomething()** when the user **clicks outside** of the modal to dismiss it (click in modal overlay).

For that purpose I need to register when the modal has been dismissed.

Q1. Is there an event for dismissed modal?

Q2. How can I **doSomething()** the Angular 2 way (no JQuery) once the modal has been dismissed?

```
<!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal" (dismissed)="doSomething()">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [afterClosed()](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/dialog/README.md) method, which returns an observable which emits the data you are interested in.

Comment: Hi I'm trying to find the simplest way to do so with [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/) and angular2. I have the [Angular2-Materialize framework](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize).

Comment: @coder your link does not work can you please check it again